# How to push to a specific branch on bitbucket using git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I understand that the command

```
git push <url>
```

is what you're supposed to use to push but as I understand it that just pushes to the master branch.  How do I push to different branches on this project.  Can someone explain how this works because I don't understand it?

Comment: Check the branch out you want to push, then use git push

Comment: @Ferrybig What do you mean check it out?

Comment: @Joris maybe try looking that up?

Comment: Start by reading https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the name of the branch along with the command.
Like,

`git push origin your_branch`

It will push `your_branch` branch in your local system to `your_branch` in the remote machine.
But if you want to push a branch called `your_local_branch` to a remote branch named `your_remote_branch`, then you should type -

`git push origin your_remote_branch:your_local_branch`.

Comment: well its the worked for me, but the other way around :  git push origin your_local_branch:your_remote_branch. thanks !!

Answer (score 4):

`git checkout -b branch1`

creates & checks out a branch `branch1`

do your work, `git add`, `git commit` etc

`git push origin branch1` pushes to the branch called `branch1`

Best quick guide is here
http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/